How to have two different markers and colors for different hues?
I am trying to plot a graph where there are two conditions and each condition must have different markers and different shades of the same color. But I am getting error
ValueError: Unrecognized marker style ['o', 'X']. How to troubleshoot this?
Here is the code:
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.markers as mrk
from matplotlib.colors import to_rgb, to_rgba


data_PB1 = pd.read_csv("....csv")
data_PB1.head()
nameOrder = ['200nt','400nt', '800nt']
color_dict = {'NoNS2': to_rgba('#0173b2', 0.3),
              'NS2': to_rgba('#0173b2', 0.8)}
palette = [color_dict[hue] for hue in ['NoNS2', 'NS2']]

marker_dict={'NoNS2':'o', 'NS2':'X'}
marker=[marker_dict[hue] for hue in ['NoNS2', 'NS2']]


ax = sns.stripplot(data=data_PB1, x='Target', y='Value', edgecolor='black', 
                   jitter=True, dodge=True, linewidth=1.2, s=13, hue="Condition", 
                   hue_order=['NoNS2', 'NS2'], palette=palette, alpha= 0.8,marker=marker)

sns.despine()
ax.legend( ['-NS2','+NS2'], bbox_to_anchor=(0.85, 1), loc=2, fontsize = 12, borderaxespad=0.,frameon=False)
plt.ylim(0,7)
plt.yticks(fontsize=12)
plt.xticks(fontsize=12)

for legend_handle in ax.get_legend().legendHandles:  
       legend_handle.set_edgecolor('black')
    
plt.savefig('Figures/PB1_Segment.pdf', format='pdf', bbox_inches = "tight")



The sns.striplot (see doc) passes the **kwargs (including marker) to matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter(). In turn, to achieve multiple marker in the same matplotlib scatterplot, it looks like you have to call the scatter command multiple times (see this question). In summary, I think you have to call stripplot twice (one for each condition) on the same figure.
